# Can I work out the regression coefficients from the betas and the t-values?

Tags: multiple-regression

I have t and beta (the estimate of the standardized coefficient), but I didn't write down the coefficients or their standard errors.  How can I work out the unstandardized coefficients?

Comment: How can you have beta but not the coefficient?

Comment: @gung I assume "I didn't write down" in the question suggests the OP has only what they specifically wrote down at some previous time, and don't have the original data (maybe they were at a presentation and wrote down only what was on a slide, or maybe it's the OP's work but the data has since been lost). Such situations of limited information regularly occur when trying to read papers as well, if the paper only gives some of the desired information.

Comment: @Glen_b, that still doesn't make sense to me. The beta is the coefficient.

Comment: @gung not to people in psych (and related social-science areas) it's not -- see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_coefficient. When they say "beta" they're NOT talking about $\hat{\beta}$ or the thing it estimates    (yes, this means when someone says "beta" we don't know what they mean. Yes I want to smack the first person who decided to call a standardized $b$ (standardized $\hat{\beta}$) "beta", flipping the bird to notational conventions, But that's how it is.)... ctd

Comment: ctd ... ... worse a lot of  people in these areas are *never* exposed to the usual notation in stats (the sample estimates are always '$b$'s and the population values are never mentioned notationally), so they don't even realize what they're saying is directly misleading the statisticians. There's a ton of other little confusions to run into. Lots of questions on site use this terminology ("beta" for a standardized coefficient). It's very common when responses are things like Likert scales (derived from a sum of Likert-items on questionnaires) that don't have meaningful units.